# qcheckbox not changing checked state when clicked on

Tags: qt, checkbox, signals-slots, qcheckbox

I have been developing a GUI, and have run into an issue (or possible bug) with a `QCheckBox`.

Adding a QCheckBox component to my form, compiling and running it has no issues. However, when clicking on the checkbox, no visible feedback is displayed.

I added a listener for the `clicked(bool)` signal It is used in the debug output to display the current state, which does change.

Only 3 settings are changed on the checkbox:

1. Component Text
2. Component Name
3. Component Checkedstate : Checked.

I added another checkbox to the page, recompiled and ran it without changing anything. Again, this new checkbox does not respond to changes.

Furthermore, I created a new project, added only a checkbox, compiled and ran it. Had no issues displaying the state change. Must be an issue with my project.

Output of `stateChanged(int)` and `clicked(bool)` signals: (`qDebug()` output)

```
QCHECKBOX STATE (stateChanged):  "2"
QCHECKBOX STATE (clicked):  "checked"
QCHECKBOX STATE (stateChanged):  "0"
QCHECKBOX STATE (clicked):  "unchecked"
QCHECKBOX STATE (stateChanged):  "2"
QCHECKBOX STATE (clicked):  "checked"
QCHECKBOX STATE (stateChanged):  "0"
QCHECKBOX STATE (clicked):  "unchecked"
```

If any additional project info is required, feel free to leave a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a *possible* solution for solving this "missing check/mark" issue.

I implemented the CSS "indicator" solution I got from this [qt form post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/27476/solved-qcheckbox-background-color/6) which is problematic.

**Sources of solution:**

- Doc page: [here](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget)
- Implementation: [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/4941-qCheckbox-back-ground-color)

**Example Implementation:**

```
QPalette p = ui->checkBox->palette();
p.setColor(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Base, QColor(255, 255, 255));
p.setColor(QPalette::Button, QColor(255, 255, 255));
ui->checkBox->setAutoFillBackground(true);
ui->checkBox->setPalette(p);
```

the `QColor(255, 255, 255)` will be the background color you desire, e.g. your window background color.

the `QPallete::Active`, `QPalette::base` refers to the active checkbox's background (the white box background)

and the `QPalette::Button` refers to the "actual background" (behind the checkbox and the checkbox text)

Hope this helps!